# I am not sure why it will not print the school name info to the text file as well

Tags: javascript, html

I am completely new to web design. I am trying to send the form data to a .txt file. Currently it only sends the form data for personal information only. Ideally I would like to send all the form data to a txt file. I am not sure what's the problem here. I would appreciate any help.

Build.HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Resumaker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src = "main_test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header> 
    <nav>
        <h1> RESUMAKER </h1>
            <ul>
                <li style="float:right"><a class = "active" 
                href="build.html" target="_blank"><span> Build a Resume 
                </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="createaccount.html" target="_blank"><span> 
                Create Account </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="signin.html" target="_blank"><span> Sign in 
                </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="resources.html" target="_blank"><span> 
                Resources </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contacts.html" target="_blank"><span> Talk to 
                us </span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

<h1 class = "third"><strong> Build your resume here! </strong></h1>

<h2 class = "fourth"> YOUR PERSONAL INFO </h2>

<form autocomplete="on" method="post" class = "fourth">
    <input onclick="saveFormAsTextFile()" type="button" value = "Make your 
    resume" />
    <input type="reset"><br><br>
    <label for = "first_name"> <br><b>First name:</b> </label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id = "first_name" 
    placeholder="John" autofocus /><br>
    <label for = "last_name"> <b>Last name:</b> </label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id = "last_name" placeholder="Doe" 
    /><br>
    <label for = "user_email"> <b>Email:</b> </label>
    <input type="email" name="user_email" id = "user_email" 
    placeholder="johndoe@gotham.com" autocomplete="off" /><br>
    <label for = "phone_number"> <b>Phone Number:</b> </label>
    <input name="phone_number" type="number" id = "phone_number" 
    placeholder="(987)-654-3210" /><br>
    <label for = "location"> <b>Location:</b> </label>
    <input type="text" name="location" id = "location" placeholder="Gotham 
    City" autofocus /><br>
    <label for = "linkedin"> <b>LinkedIn:</b> </label>
    <input type="url" name="linkedin" id = "linkedin" autofocus /><br>
    <label for="filename"> <b>Filename</b></label>
    <input type = "text" id="filename" value="" size="40" 
    placeholder="title.md">
    <br/><br/>
</form>

<br><h2 class = "fourth"> YOUR EDUCATIONAL BACKGROUND </h2>

<form autocomplete="on" method="post" class = "fourth">
    <label for = "heading1"> <b>Section Heading: </b></label>
    <input type="text" name="heading1" id="heading1" placeholder="Education" 
    ><br>
    <label for = "school_name"> <b>School Name:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="school_name" id="school_name" 
    placeholder="Gotham University"><br>
    <label for = "school_location"> <b>School Location:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="school_location" id="school_location" 
    placeholder="Gotham City"><br>
    <label for = "degree"> <b>Degree:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="degree" id="degree" placeholder="B.S."><br>
    <label for = "major"> <b>Major:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="major" autocomplete="off" id="major" 
    placeholder="Chemical Engineering"><br>
    <label for = "gpa"> <b>GPA:</b></label> 
    <input type="number" name="gpa" id="gpa" placeholder="Out of 4.0"><br>
    <label for = "start_date"> <b>Start Date:</b></label> 
    <input type="month" name="start_date" id="start_date" value="2018-07-22" 
    /><br>
    <label for = "end_date"> <b>End Date:</b></label> 
    <input type="month" name="end_date" id="end_date" value="2018-07-22" /> 
    <br><br><br>
</form>
<br><h2 class = "fourth"> YOUR WORK EXPERIENCE </h2>

<form autocomplete="on" method="post" class = "fourth">
    <label for = "heading2"> <b>Section Heading: </b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="heading2" id = "heading_2" placeholder="Work 
    Experience" ><br>
    <label for = "company_name"><b>Company Name:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="company_name" id = "company_name" 
    placeholder="Detective Comics"><br>
    <label for = "job_location"><b>Job Location:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="job_location" id = "job_location" 
    placeholder="Gotham City"><br>
    <label for = "job_title"><b>Job Title:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="job_title" id = "job_title" placeholder="B.S."> 
    <br>
    <label for = "job_responsibilities"><b>Job Responsibilities:</b></label> 
    <input name="job_responsibilities" id = "job_responsibilities" 
    type="text"><br><br>
    <label for = "start_date"><b>Start Date:</b></label>
    <input type="month" name="start_date" id = "start_date" value="2018-07- 
    22" /><br>
    <label for = "end_date"><b>End Date:</b></label>
    <input type="month" name="end_date" id ="end_date" value="2018-07-22" /> 
    <br><br><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

main_test.js:

```
function saveFormAsTextFile()

    {
    var textToSave =
      '\r\n\n'+
      'First Name: ' + document.getElementById('first_name').value + ' \r\n' 
      + 
      'Last Name: ' + document.getElementById('last_name').value + ' \r\n' + 
      'Email: ' + document.getElementById('user_email').value + ' \r\n' +
      'Phone Number: ' + document.getElementById('phone_number').value + ' 
      \r\n' + 
      'Location: ' + document.getElementById('location').value + ' \r\n' + 
      'LinkedIn: ' + document.getElementById('linkedin').value + ' \r\n' 
      'School Name: ' + document.getElementById('school_name').value + ' 
      \r\n';

    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("filename").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();

    }

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

```js
function saveFormAsTextFile()

    {    
      var textToSave = '\r\n\n'+
      'First Name: ' + document.getElementById('first_name').value + ' \r\n'+ 
      'Last Name: ' + document.getElementById('last_name').value + ' \r\n' + 
      'Email: ' + document.getElementById('user_email').value + ' \r\n' +
      'Phone Number: ' + document.getElementById('phone_number').value + ' \r\n' + 
      'Location: ' + document.getElementById('location').value + ' \r\n' + 
      'LinkedIn: ' + document.getElementById('linkedin').value + ' \r\n' +
      'School Name: ' + document.getElementById('school_name').value + ' \r\n';

   /* var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("filename").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();*/
    
    //---For CSV
     var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
      downloadLink.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
      downloadLink.target = '_blank';
      downloadLink.download = 'resume.csv';
      downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();

    }

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Resumaker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src = "main_test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header> 
    <nav>
        <h1> RESUMAKER </h1>
            <ul>
                <li style="float:right"><a class = "active" 
                href="build.html" target="_blank"><span> Build a Resume 
                </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="createaccount.html" target="_blank"><span> 
                Create Account </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="signin.html" target="_blank"><span> Sign in 
                </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="resources.html" target="_blank"><span> 
                Resources </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contacts.html" target="_blank"><span> Talk to 
                us </span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

<h1 class = "third"><strong> Build your resume here! </strong></h1>

<h2 class = "fourth"> YOUR PERSONAL INFO </h2>

<form autocomplete="on" method="post" class = "fourth">
    <input onclick="saveFormAsTextFile()" type="button" value = "Make your 
    resume" />
    <input type="reset"><br><br>
    <label for = "first_name"> <br><b>First name:</b> </label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id = "first_name" 
    placeholder="John" autofocus /><br>
    <label for = "last_name"> <b>Last name:</b> </label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id = "last_name" placeholder="Doe" 
    /><br>
    <label for = "user_email"> <b>Email:</b> </label>
    <input type="email" name="user_email" id = "user_email" 
    placeholder="johndoe@gotham.com" autocomplete="off" /><br>
    <label for = "phone_number"> <b>Phone Number:</b> </label>
    <input name="phone_number" type="number" id = "phone_number" 
    placeholder="(987)-654-3210" /><br>
    <label for = "location"> <b>Location:</b> </label>
    <input type="text" name="location" id = "location" placeholder="Gotham 
    City" autofocus /><br>
    <label for = "linkedin"> <b>LinkedIn:</b> </label>
    <input type="url" name="linkedin" id = "linkedin" autofocus /><br>
    <label for="filename"> <b>Filename</b></label>
    <input type = "text" id="filename" value="" size="40" 
    placeholder="title.md">
    <br/><br/>
</form>

<br><h2 class = "fourth"> YOUR EDUCATIONAL BACKGROUND </h2>

<form autocomplete="on" method="post" class = "fourth">
    <label for = "heading1"> <b>Section Heading: </b></label>
    <input type="text" name="heading1" id="heading1" placeholder="Education" 
    ><br>
    <label for = "school_name"> <b>School Name:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="school_name" id="school_name" 
    placeholder="Gotham University"><br>
    <label for = "school_location"> <b>School Location:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="school_location" id="school_location" 
    placeholder="Gotham City"><br>
    <label for = "degree"> <b>Degree:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="degree" id="degree" placeholder="B.S."><br>
    <label for = "major"> <b>Major:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="major" autocomplete="off" id="major" 
    placeholder="Chemical Engineering"><br>
    <label for = "gpa"> <b>GPA:</b></label> 
    <input type="number" name="gpa" id="gpa" placeholder="Out of 4.0"><br>
    <label for = "start_date"> <b>Start Date:</b></label> 
    <input type="month" name="start_date" id="start_date" value="2018-07-22" 
    /><br>
    <label for = "end_date"> <b>End Date:</b></label> 
    <input type="month" name="end_date" id="end_date" value="2018-07-22" /> 
    <br><br><br>
</form>
<br><h2 class = "fourth"> YOUR WORK EXPERIENCE </h2>

<form autocomplete="on" method="post" class = "fourth">
    <label for = "heading2"> <b>Section Heading: </b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="heading2" id = "heading_2" placeholder="Work 
    Experience" ><br>
    <label for = "company_name"><b>Company Name:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="company_name" id = "company_name" 
    placeholder="Detective Comics"><br>
    <label for = "job_location"><b>Job Location:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="job_location" id = "job_location" 
    placeholder="Gotham City"><br>
    <label for = "job_title"><b>Job Title:</b></label> 
    <input type="text" name="job_title" id = "job_title" placeholder="B.S."> 
    <br>
    <label for = "job_responsibilities"><b>Job Responsibilities:</b></label> 
    <input name="job_responsibilities" id = "job_responsibilities" 
    type="text"><br><br>
    <label for = "start_date"><b>Start Date:</b></label>
    <input type="month" name="start_date" id = "start_date" value="2018-07- 
    22" /><br>
    <label for = "end_date"><b>End Date:</b></label>
    <input type="month" name="end_date" id ="end_date" value="2018-07-22" /> 
    <br><br><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you mean?

Comment: Do you think there is a way to send this form data to a CSV using just HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: I did not try adding the values to text boxes just ran the code and hit the "Make your resume" button and it opened a notepad file for me. Try running my code.

Comment: It works now. I am trying to figure out a way to send this form data to a CSV using just HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: It is possible to send this form data to csv. I am editing my answer to include it.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you think if there is a way to be able to create sort of like a database in Excel with all the inputted info? I have been looking up online but most people are using back-end languages or doing stuff with Google Forms, which seems to be easy but I don't know how sufficient that would be.

Comment: I am not sure. You will have to research and try various options.